# Mule flow not able to read the inbound attachmnet

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, mule-esb

I have this mule flow , where its polling the source folder to read the text file which I am adding as a attachment and sending through REST call , the same attachment I am trying to read in the different flow but inbound attachment is coming as null , please have a look into the code and help me on this.

```
<flow name="createAttachment" doc:description="Reading file and sending as attachment.">
    <file:inbound-endpoint path="src/test/resources/in/attachment/" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>
    <file:file-to-byte-array-transformer doc:name="File to Byte Array"/>
 <!--    <set-attachment attachmentName="#[originalFilename]" value="#[payload]" contentType="multipart/form-data" doc:name="Attachment"/>  -->
  <set-attachment attachmentName="#[originalFilename]" value="#[payload]" contentType="multipart/form-data" doc:name="Attachment" />
    <http:request config-ref="HTTP_Request_Configuration" path="attachment/excel"  method="POST" doc:name="HTTP"/>
</flow>


<flow name="readAttachment">
 <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="attachment/excel" allowedMethods="POST" parseRequest="false" />
    <set-payload value="#[message.inboundAttachments['myattachment.txt']]" doc:name="Retrieve Attachments"/> 
      <set-payload value="#[payload.getInputStream() ]" doc:name="Get Inputstream from Payload"/>
        <file:outbound-endpoint path="src/test/resources/out/attachment" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File" outputPattern="#[server.dateTime.toString()].pdf"/>

</flow>
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the following:

```
<flow name="readAttachment">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration"
        path="/" allowedMethods="POST" parseRequest="false" doc:name="HTTP" />
    <byte-array-to-string-transformer doc:name="Byte Array to String"/>
    <logger message="#[payload]" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger" /><file:outbound-endpoint path="src/test/resources" connector-ref="File" responseTimeout="10000" doc:name="File"/>

</flow>
```

When the attachment was received it was automatically parsed to be the payload, so it was just a case of turning the byte array to string.

I hope this helps